# how to configure mongodb to always cache 100% of a collection on RAM?

Tags: database, mongodb, caching, nosql

let's suppose that the machine has 100 GB of RAM and that a particular collection only has 10 GB of data.

That's only 10% of the total RAM.

So is it possible to configure this setup such that the entire collection is always cached on RAM, for performance of course?

EDITED:

based upon this documentaiong:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

If the RAM is 100 GB, then by default MongoDB will use `(100 - 1) / 2 = 49.5` GB of RAM as cache.

Since the collection is only 10 GB, will this essentially guarantee that 100% of the collection is 100% of the time cached in this allocated RAM space?

Comment: question edited. Based on the documentation, 49.5 GB of the 100 GB of RAM will be dedicated to caching. Does that imply that the 10 GB collection will always sit on the RAM?